# How to add item to main django admin site without creating any database tables

Tags: django

How to add app item to main django admin site menu without creating any database tables. So then i can just overwrite admin template for this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `admin/foo/` urls to your own views in your URLConf.  See "Creating Custom Admin Views" here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/

Now you just need to add links to it.  [Override your favorite admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), and add the link over there.

Comment: The latest Django Book's chapter 17 is not related to creating custom admin views, unfortunately. That URL is not pointing to the right place; you can see what the older Chapter 17 looked like here: http://py3k.cn/chapter17/en/ (it doesn't look like the new book touches upon extending admin views at all..!)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create an [custom admin view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) that is independent of the models in your application and override the `admin/index.html` to include the new link explicitly. Alternatively, you can also override the `get_urls` in the `AdminSite` class

There are saner and better ways to add a new custom admin view. If you still want to use a model however, you can simply extend a django model and mark it as a [proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and override it's template.